# widget home screen or app widget

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

I'm making an assignment about widgets but I wanna learn firstly difference between app widgets and home screen widgets? Is there any difference? what can i care about them while im explain them

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any difference?

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html):

> App Widgets are miniature application views that can be embedded in other applications (such as the Home screen) and receive periodic updates.

In most cases, app widgets are "home screen widgets".

Answer (score 0):

App Widgets can be added to either home screen or the lock screen or even to a custom app widget host for that matter.

Home Screen Widgets are just a sub set of app widgets. As the name suggests, they can only be hosted in home screen.

Answer (score -1):

you can read all about Widgets here:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html

Comment: okey thank you. if i research about the app widgets for the assignment , it doesnt matter?

Comment: @inflacort did you read through the link I provided?  The answer to your question is in that link, go down to the first paragraph under where it says "Widget limitations" and start reading.  I encourage you to read the entire page for your assignment and you will understand a lot more about what a widget is.  Good luck!